# How to show dynamic date as Header in the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter, kotlin-android

I want to show the date dynamically in the header of the RecyclerView and group the items of that date inside it.

My data class looks something like this

```
data class Feed(
    val id: String = "",
    val title: String = "",
    val createdAt: Long = 0L,
)
```

And I have to create a view something like this

[image]

Will any of you please help me with this? I'm trying to solve it for the last 2 days. But not able to figure out how exactly I get this one?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You can handle with view type

Comment: Are you using room data base just want more context

Comment: I dont understand the question... do you need to know how to create a recycler view with differents viewholders?

Comment: Yes, I'm using room db

Comment: I know I have to use with ViewType but how to group and positioning will be done